# Scala using self as a Type

Tags: scala, types

I am following a tutorial that attempts to explain the usage of self types. The following example uses the self type to say any Writeable is writable for its own type.

```
trait Writes[In, Out] {
  def write(in: In): Out
}

trait Writeable[Self] {
  def write[Out]()(implicit writes: Writes[Self, Out]): Out =
    writes.write(this)
}
```

I get a compilation error on the invocation of the *write* function of type Writes[Self, Out]. Intuitively, this should work since the parameters of writes [in] is of type Self. However the compiler says no ...

```
found : Writable.this.type (with underlying type Writeable[Self])
  required: Self
    writes.write(self)
```

What is the correct way to express these types and relations?

I am not sure if the tutorial is targeting an older version of Scala. Also, please excuse my inability to correctly express the problem, I am new to Scala.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with "self types". You're just using the label `Self` to represent a type parameter. This code would be exactly the same if you had used `T` instead of `Self`.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably delete the question then?

Comment: You might return to the tutorial for a review and then clarify your question. As it is, it's not clear what you're trying to do and/or learn.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question obviously should *not* compile, it is not a problem with the Scala compiler (you will find no version that would compile this, no matter how far back you go). I don't know what kind of tutorial you are reading, but I'm for some reason sure that you wanted this:

```
trait Writes[In, Out] {
  def write(in: In): Out
}

trait Writeable[Self] { self: Self =>
  def write[Out]()(implicit writes: Writes[Self, Out]): Out =
    writes.write(this)
}
```

This compiles just fine, because now you have enforced that `this` is of type `Self` by the `self: Self =>`-self type declaration.